# How to add an image in the title bar using html?

Tags: html, wamp

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    some text

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I wrote to add an image in the new tab bar of the browser.
But this is not working.
I am also using wamp server, if wamp might be causing problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), the most browser-compatible incantation is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

After that, you just need to worry about whether your browser is actually downloading the icon. What do the server logs say? Have you checked your browsers network debugging console?

Comment: I checked the console and the browser is not loading the icon....
How to correct this problem?

Comment: As @verbose-mode said, clear cache and reload. If it's not being REQUESTED, then you've got a parse error in your HTML preventing it (the favicon rel) being recognised. If it's not being LOADED, then you've probably got the wrong icon path.

Answer (score 6):

W3C says:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
[…]
</head>
[…]
</html>
```

See http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

But keep in mind: Some browser need a while to recognize that there is a favicon - try to delete the cookies and reopen your site! (And be sure the icon is at the path :) )

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/iconimg.png" />
```

NB: The `href` is the directory to your image example. Your image is in a folder called "img" and your image name is "iconimg" and if it is a png use `.png`, if it is a jpg then `.jpg`. Remember to do this in the head of your file and not in the body.

Answer (score 2):

I tried in my angular7 project by writing these lines and worked.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="filepath/filename.ico">
```

please be noted that the image file should be in icon format (.ico)

Answer (score 0):

in your  you have capital letters for html.you wrote it as  THIS IS NOT CORRECT!!! your browser will not understand it as html5.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Looks as if some words are missing in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

1.) Choose the image you want to set in your title bar.
2.) Convert it to ".ico" format. (You can use the following link online)
http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-ico
3.) Save the file as "favicon.ico" in the same folder as your .html file
4.) Add this inside your head tag `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Showing image in title bar is easy.
please follow the steps :

a) first save you image some where in the folder and name like favicon.
b) then use below line inside head tag of the html view

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="image_url" />
```

c) Here you must know the path of your file, where you have saved the image
d) save your image url in place of **image_url**
e) save your working.

Answer (score 0):

it works

Add this inside your head tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with this code, and it worked for me: `<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="C:\Users\nrm05\Pictures\logo.jpg" />`
Be sure to type `type="image/jpg"` for jpg files, and `type="image/png"` for PNG files. If you haven't downloaded the image, but you know the image URL, then you can type it in like this: `href="image_url"`

Hope this answered your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys! I got it with the first result that popped up! Get this, when I consulted in the professional website W3B or whatever, their result wasn't working!

Thanks again!

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

Code ^

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31206761)